# Limit the number of taxonomy terms diplayed

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, categories, custom-taxonomy

I have 2 taxonomy sets **`product_cat`** and **`tvshows_cat`**. There are 12 terms for each set.

A product can have, up to 12 terms *(but never from the 2 sets at the same time)*.

I use this code to show the term list in the product page:

```
$cats = get_the_term_list($post->ID, 'product_cat', '', '  ', ''); 
$tvcats = get_the_term_list($post->ID, 'tvshows_cat', '', '  ', ''); 

if (!empty($cats)){
    echo strip_tags($cats, '   ');
}elseif(!empty($tvcats)){
    echo strip_tags($tvcats, '    ');
}
```

The result is:

> ***Action, Drama, Adventure, Biography, Animation***

The problem is that, in some cases, there is not enough space to show all terms.

I need to limit number of terms to 2 terms.

**Question:**

How can I limit the number of terms applied to two?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **Instead using `get_the_term_list()` function, you should use `get_the_terms()` which will give you directly an array of terms objects** *(as `get_the_term_list()` is using `get_the_terms()` herself if you look to the source code of the function)*.

Then that you can build a **custom function** to get what you want *(I will **not use implode() function** or **any other one** php function as we want only 2 terms.)*

**Note:** You don't need `strip_tags()` function here

So your code will be:

```
// This function goes first
function get_my_terms( $post_id, $taxonomy ){
    $cats = get_the_terms( $post_id, $taxonomy );

    foreach($cats as $cat) $cats_arr[] = $cat->name;

    if ( count($cats_arr) > 1) $cats_str = $cats_arr[0] . ', ' . $cats_arr[1]; // return first 2 terms
    elseif ( count($cats_arr) == 1) $cats_str = $cats_arr[0]; // return one term
    else $cats_str = '';

    return $cats_str;
}
```

*This code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or any plugin files…*

Then below is your code:

```
$cats = get_my_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' ); 
$tvcats = get_my_terms( $post->ID, 'tvshows_cat' ); 

// Displaying 2 categories terms max
echo $cats . $tvcats;
```

*This code goes on your php templates file*

---

> **— update —** *(related to author comment)*

Or without function, your code will be:

```
// Product categories
$cats = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );

foreach($cats as $cat) $cats_arr[] = $cat->name;

if ( count($cats_arr) > 1) $cats_str = $cats_arr[0] . ', ' . $cats_arr[1]; // return first 2 terms
elseif ( count($cats_arr) == 1) $cats_str = $cats_arr[0]; // return one term
else $cats_str = '';

// TV shows categories
$tvcats = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'tvshows_cat' );

foreach($tvcats as $tvcat) $tvcat_arr[] = $tvcat->name;

if ( count($tvcat_arr) > 1) $tvcats_str = $tvcat_arr[0] . ', ' . $tvcat_arr[1]; // return first 2 terms
elseif ( count($tvcat_arr) == 1) $tvcats_str = $tvcat_arr[0]; // return one term
else $tvcats_str = '';

// The Display of 2 categories
echo $cats_str . $tvcats_str;
```

*This code goes on your php templates files*

**This code is tested and works.**

Comment: could we only use template code?how can we use code only in template, not function?

Comment: Yes, but is better to use the alternative version without a custom function.

Answer (score 4):

you can also using `explode()` with `array_slice()` for this problem .

for example :

```
function display_limited_terms($items){
    $filter = explode(',', $items);
    $a = array_slice($filter, 0, 2);
    foreach ($a as $b) {
        echo $b;
    }
}


$cats = get_the_term_list($post->ID, 'product_cat', '', '  ', '');
$tvcats = get_the_term_list($post->ID, 'tvshows_cat', '', '  ', '');

if (!empty($cats)) {

    display_limited_terms(strip_tags($cats, '   '));
} elseif (!empty($tvcats)) {

    display_limited_terms(strip_tags($cats, '   '));
}
```

Comment: komak khasti bego .

Comment: I dont want to use function.php.

Comment: you do not using function.php for this problem . just add top code in the template file .

Answer (score 3):

I am assuming your final output is a comma separated string - Action, Drama, Adventure, Biography, Animation.

To show only two items you can

```
$items = "item1, item2, item3, item4";

$filter = explode(',', $items);

for( $i=0; $i<2; $i++ ) {
    echo $filter[$i];
}
```

Try replacing the code you provided above with the following

```
    function display_limited_terms( $items ) {
        $filter = explode(',', $items);

        for( $i=0; $i<2; $i++ ) {
            echo $filter[$i];
        }
    }


    $cats = get_the_term_list($post->ID, 'product_cat', '', '  ', '');
    $tvcats = get_the_term_list($post->ID, 'tvshows_cat', '', '  ', '');

    if (!empty($cats)){

        display_limited_terms( strip_tags($cats, '   ') );
    }

    elseif(!empty($tvcats)) {

        display_limited_terms( strip_tags($cats, '   ') );
    }
```

Comment: How can i use this? where to put it?